# Pass Method to Child Component

Tags: angular

I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.deleteFile is not a function
```

I thought this was possible but am not able to find any resource. In React this is possible.

Here's my method in my parent component:

```
public deleteFile(f: File) {
   this.fileState.delete(f.name); }
```

The template:

```
<app-file *ngFor="let file of files" [file]="file" (deleteFile)="deleteFile(file.name)"></app-file>
```

and lastly my file (child) component:

```
@Input() deleteFile: () => void;
```

it's HTML:

```
<button type="button" mat-stroked-button color="warning" (click)="deleteFile(file.name)">Delete file</button>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

@penleychan pointed me in the right direction. I instead implemented an event emitter like so:

file.component:

```
@Output() deleted = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" mat-stroked-button color="warning" (click)="delete()">Delete file</button>
```

parent HTML:

```
<app-file *ngFor="let file of files" [file]="file" (deleted)="onDelete($event)"></app-file>
```

Thanks all. Looks like I just misunderstood how to implement this.

Comment: why do you want to pass a function? you could simply write the logic in parent component

Comment: I must be missing something. The logic IS in the parent component. I just want to pass a reference to that method to the child.

Comment: Your child component will just emit the value (`@Output()`) to your parent via `EventEmitter<T>`. Don't need to pass a method to child component

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed the `deleteFile` as an input. You are only emitting the `deleteFile` event from the child. Notice the use of `[]` for `@Input()` and `()` for `@Output()` (or any other event).

Comment: Any tips for how I could accomplish what I'm trying to do the correct way?

Comment: instead of `(deleteFile)='...'`, you need to do `[deleteFile]='deleteFile'` , this will pass the function to the child. You can write your logic in the deleteFile function.

Comment: If I change to [deleteFile]="deleteFile" notice without () I get error "Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined" with the parentheses I get the above error that it is not a function.

Comment: with `()` you are emitting event from the child and handling the logic in the parent component. With `[]`, you are passing the function to the child, so all the variables that you are using in the function should be available (the fileState variable is `undefined` in your case). If you need more help with the code, please create a reproduction on stackblitz